# Determine if a variable is an instance of any class

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance, isinstance

How to determine if a variable is an instance in Python 3? I consider something to be an instance if it has `__dict__` attribute.

Example:

```
is_instance_of_any_class(5)  # should return False
is_instance_of_any_class([2, 3])  # should return False

class A:
  pass

a = A()
is_instance_of_any_class(a)  # should return True
```

I have seen messages about using `isinstance(x, type)` or `inspect.isclass(x)` but this would give True for the class (A), not the instance.

Comment: Since everything is an object, everything is an instance of *something*… What's the use case? Please ensure you don't have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: *"I consider something to be an instance if it has `__dict__` attribute."* – Sooo… `hasattr(o, '__dict__')`…?

Comment: Yeah, i think checking for `__dict__` is better

Comment: Not just better, but it's exactly what the OP wants. All the talk about detecting "instances" is a red herring, because everything *is* an instance, whether or not it has a `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: I think OP's understanding of what is an _instance_ is wrong, since everything is an object in python, so `5` is an object of class `int` and `[2,3]` is an object of class `list` and so on. `isinstance(x, y)` is the way to go if you just want to check if `x` is an object of `y`, but if you want to check if `x` is an object of builtin class or your own custom defined class then you should be checking `__dict__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your understanding of what an instance is wrong here, since everything is an object in python, so `5` is an object of class `int` and `[2,3]` is an object of class `list` and so on.

`isinstance(x, y)` is the way to go if you just want to check if `x` is an object of `y`, but if you want to check if `x` is an object of builtin class or your own custom defined class then you should be checking the existence of `__dict__` using `hasattr(x, '__dict__')`.

Answer (score 0):

the `__module__` attribute of the type of the object can help. check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56298786/18183594 :

> Check the **module** attribute of the type. That tells you where the type was defined.
>
> ```
> >>> class Test: pass
> ... 
> >>> a = 42
> >>> b = Test()
> >>> type(a).__module__
> 'builtins'
> >>> type(b).__module__
> '__main__'
> ```
>
> When classes from other modules are involved it's a bit less trivial, but that was true in Python 2 as well.

Comment: I edited this for completness but the answer is wrong because [2,3] is a list and it'lll be rturned a s a 'builtins