# Check that a variable value is an instance of any class

Tags: python, instance, inspect

How to check properly that a variable value is an instance of any class?

For example:

```
class Foo:
    pass

isinstance_of_any_class(isinstance)  # Return False
isinstance_of_any_class(Foo)  # Return False
isinstance_of_any_class(Foo())  # Return True
```

I have looked at:

- `isinstance` - takes two mandatory arguments: `object` and `classinfo`
- [Determine if a variable is an instance of any class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163023/determine-if-a-variable-is-an-instance-of-any-class) - question's author wanted to distinguish instances of builtin types from user-defined, but I want to distinguish instances from methods, function, classes an so on
- The `inspect` module - doesn't have `isinstance` only the following members that near needed:  `ismodule`, `isclass`, `ismethod`, `isfunction`, `isgeneratorfunction`, `isgenerator`, `iscoroutinefunction`, `iscoroutine`, `isawaitable`, `isasyncgen`, `istraceback`, `isframe`, `iscode`, `isbuiltin`, `isroutine`, `isabstract`, `ismethoddescriptor`, `isdatadescriptor`, `isgetsetdescriptor`, `ismemberdescriptor`

The desired function could be implemented by negation of every other possible object type through `inspect`'s members. How can I do it *without* enumerating all of `inspect`'s members?

Comment: Is it possible for you to do it like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/395782/8702713

Comment: @thisisjaymehta Thanks for response! No, in my question is assumed that you know nothing about the possible classes of the object if it is instance

Comment: If you do `type(Foo)` and `type(isinstance)` you can see they both *are* instances of a class. Everything in Python is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , and how your comment helps me and other who wants to distinguish somehow more intuitive instances from everything that can be checked by `inspect` module members. See "Extra" section, please.

Comment: What is the *context* in which you're trying to do that? What problem is it solving?

Comment: My class accepts the callable object: it can be something that accepts `object()` usage. But only for class instances (that not a function, a class definition and something like that) I want to take instance variable with known name. Nevertheless, I can figure out the workaround in current problem by myself. I am curious about the topic in general.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking can be a bit tricky, I could not find any helpful documentation except for the inspect module.

Anyway, This will cover most of the cases:

```py
import inspect

def isinstance_of_any_class(o):
  if inspect.isclass(o): return False # Is a class or a type such int, float...
  elif not hasattr(o, '__dict__'): return False # Is a function
  else: return True
```

Comment: Not everything without a `__dict__` is a function. You can write classes with `__slots__`, for example, and instances of built-in types often don't have it either (`hasattr(1, '__dict__')`).